# Query android contacts, with a list of multiple phone numbers, in single query

Tags: android, list, android-contacts

Is it possible to query android contacts, with a list of phone numbers and get phone contacts cursor only for those phone numbers. Rather than having to query each mobile number single i.e. one-by-one looping. I want to achieve this in one single query.

For e.g.  mobile numbers available with me (These numbers may run into 100's): 
1234567890
1234567892
1234567893
1234567324
1234566740
1232347890

If user has stored only say : 1234567890 phone number in his contacts, I want a cursor with only 1 record to loop through. I dont want to loop through the whole contacts book.

Current solutions available on StackOverflow are all pointing to query mobile number one-by-one, but this is a slow process.

Some samples like these are available, but do not fit my requirement:

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

people.moveToFirst();

do {

    // Do work...

} while (people.moveToNext());
```

This should be possible by running single query with IN clause & looping only the relevant records.